# Check if word is in proximity of another word

Tags: python

I am trying to verify if words from a list are in proximity to words from another list. I define proximity as words that are near each other by a range of 5 words.

I tried using the following regular expression, but with little success:

```
\b(word1|word2|word3)(?:\W+\w+){1,6}?\W+(word1|word2|word3)\b
```

I was able to use the following code, but only to check the proximity between two words:

```
import re

text = ("If you want to use the same regular expression more than once, you should compile it into a regular expression object. ")

def search(target, text, context=5):
    words = re.findall(r'\w+', text)

    matches = (i for (i,w) in enumerate(words) if w.lower() == target)
    for index in matches:
        if index < context //2:
            yield words[0:context+1]
        elif index > len(words) - context//2 - 1:
            yield words[-(context+1):]
        else:
            yield words[index - context//2:index + context//2 + 1]

def extract(word):
    return(list(search(word, text)))

def check(word, lst):
    if word in lst:
        print("The word is in the list")
    else:
        print("The word is not in the list")
    
def main(word1, word2, lst):
    extract(word1)
    check(word2, lst)
        
main("expression", "once", text)
```

My questions are:
First, how would you streamline the above code to make it faster on large texts?
Second, how would you go ahead to search for combination of multiple words (eg. check if one of ["expression", "banana", "same"] appears in proximity of one of ["once", "split", "use"]?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you confirmed that is it slow on larger texts? I would focus on getting it working first before trying to optimise.

Comment: Currently you are not using the result of extract for anything, so you might as well not call it = immediate speed up ;)

Comment: For large texts, i would suggest that you should avoid searching the text, like you do, but instead, take one word of the text each time and check if it exists in the list of words you are checking for proximity. That would be efficient if the words you are looking for proximity are much fewer than the words in the text